# How to fetch selected item of JComboBox data into Swing text fields?

Tags: java, database, swing, h2

I have a table in my H2 database.

```
item_name | sac_hsn | price | Tax
```

And I have `JTextfield`  fields for `hsn_code` and `price`.

Now what I want to do is when I select `item_name` from `JComboBox` then data of `hsn_code` and `price` of that item should also be fetch in the text fields.

I have done this, but it's not working:-

When I run the code then in combo box it doesn't show any item. It was blank.

```
Connection connection = null;
ResultSet rs;

public void commonMethodForSt(String query) {
    try {
        Statement st = connection.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }   
}
```

Then..

```
public void populateItemNameAndDetails() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        con = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:C:/SimpleGST/GST","sa","");
        String pname = itemcombo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        commonMethodForSt("select * from additems where item_name='"+pname+"'");
        if(rs.next()) {
//              System.out.print(set_com);
            sachsntext.setText(rs.getString("sac_hsn"));
            pricetext.setText(rs.getString("price"));
            taxtext.setText(rs.getString("TAX_RATE"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

After that I set an `ActionListener` in the combo box and called the method in it.

```
 itemcombo = new JComboBox();
    itemcombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

               populateItemNameAndDetails();

        }
    });
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code some data to replace the DB.

Comment: BTW: change `} catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }`    to `} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`   Or to put that another way: **Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()`.**

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved that by creating a method that only populates data into comboBox.

```
public void populateItemCombo() {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:C:/SimpleGST/GST", "sa", "");
    itemcombo.addItem(" ");
    commonMethodForSt("select * from additems");
    while (rs.next()) {
        itemcombo.addItem(rs.getString("item_name"));
    }
}
```

and call the method.

and the codes that i asked as question are remain same.